# Как добавить свой голосовой пакет в Windows Text To Speech?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Пишу голосового ассистента для умного дома. Раньше добавлял свой голосовой пакет в Windows Text To Speech. А щяс не могу. нашел голос Vocalizer Yuri. В Балаболке он есть. А как его добавить его в Windows Text To Speech хз. Пишу код на питоне использую пакет pyttsx3. И он воспроизводит тот голос который стоит по умолчанию в Windows. У меня есть только Microsoft Zira. Как добавить Юрия туда.